# Substitute values from another array into an array twig

Tags: php, silex

How do I insert in a twig a value from one array to another in a cycle?
for example

```
{% for day_item in template_string %}
    <div id="{{lessons.{{day_item.template_string}}.id}}" class="col-lg-2 no-padding col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Googling for "php twig dynamic variable" (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+twig+dynamic+variable), most answers seem to revolve around using the attribute function (https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html). Pretty sure this is what you need, and this question is just another variation of those? Will that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is a demo:

php code:

```
// data for twig template
$data = [
    'userIds' => [1, 2, 3],
    'users'   => [
        1 => 'Tony',
        2 => 'Allen',
        3 => 'Peter',
    ],
];
```

twig code:

```
{% for userId in userIds %}
    <li>{{ users[userId] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

just use `[ ]` in Twig to visit array value with a twig variable.

and the rendered html is

```
<li>Tony</li>
<li>Allen</li>
<li>Peter</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found Tony's solution good but tried to do it inline with literals:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="./action.php?" method="GET">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="query_term">Term:</label> 
    <select class="form-control" name="" id="query_term">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        {% set term_labels = { SP: 'Spring', SU: 'Summer', FA: 'Fall' } %}
        {% for term_value in ["SP", "SU", "FA"] %}
            {% if term_value == cur_term  %} {#TODO: provide cur_term#}
                <option value="{{ term_value }}" selected='selected'>{{ term_labels[term_value] }}</option>
            {% else %}
                <option value="{{ term_value }}">{{ term_labels[term_value] }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note: this is a bootstrap 3-ish from with dynamic select dropdown created via a twig template.